# Diferença entre "desenrascanço" e "gambiarra"

Tags: etimologia, definição

Qual a diferença entre **desenrascanço** e **gambiarra** quando se trata de soluções improvisadas?

Answer (score 1):

Desenrascanço:
Esta palavra esta mais voltada para um ato ou habilidade de sair de enrascadas ou problemas que não envolvem problemas técnicos.

Já gambiarra é mais usado na resolução de problemas técnicos de diversas áreas. Existe também um outro termo usado para gambiarra, só que de forma mais culta. Chamamos também de ajuste técnico, acaba soando de forma mais elegante.

Comment: Consegue listar exemplos exclusivos, onde uma se aplica e a outra não?

Comment: Desenrascanço é uma palavra pouco usada no dia a dia, Ex: " Nada que o afamado desenrascanço lusitano não consiga ultrapassar e,..." neste site ele mostra mais exemplos.
https://ainanas.com/must-see/desenrascanco-um-bem-valioso-da-cultura-tuga/

Gambiarra: você conseguiu consertar seu tenis de forma improvisada, com uma cola que não era a indicada ou vc conseguiu consertar algum objeto eletrônico de forma artesanal, nos falamos que fizemos uma gambiarra.

Comment: @Luciano e Jackson. Posso apenas dar um palpite, porque deste lado do Atlântico uma gambiarra é apenas um cabo com uma lâmpada na ponta. A mim parece-me que a gambiarra está para o desenrascanço tal com a camisinha está para a contraceção. A gambiarra parece-me que é sempre um objeto ou engenhoca palpável que desenrasca, mesmo que não seja solução ideal ou duradoura; por exemplo, um lençol forrado com papel de alumínio que eu pendurei em frente da porta envidraçada da varanda para proteger do sol do verão quando os estores encravaram. O desenrascanço é o ato e efeito de (ou o jeitinho para) >>

Comment: @Jacinto Eles estão, ao menos à luz do sentido de gambiarra "moderno" (no Brasil), muito parecidos. O dito "jeitinho brasileiro" é sinônimo de gambiarra, como inclusive foi noticiado aos estrangeiros na copa do mundo de 2014 no Brasil.

Comment: >> improvisar uma solução para um problema; não se resume portanto à gambiarra. O meu solucionar temporariamente o problema dos estores encravados foi um desenrascanço, mas eu não chamo desenrascanço ao lençol forrado de alúmínio. Além disso, pode haver desenrascanço sem gambiarra: por exemplo, vens viver para Setúbal, e dormes umas noites no meu sofá enquanto não te disponibiliza o apartamento que alugastes.

Comment: @Luciano, então eu estava enganado. Pensei que gambiarra fosse sempre uma engenhoca palpável.